# What do i use for multiple activities in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I made an app that contains videos.

I have a homepage with Five Buttons, and each button goes to a new activity,or layout that has a video and some text.

Now I know I could just simply code it with videoView and textView on every new activity.But is this really the best way? 
If not what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Its not best way which you used.

Its better if you pass argument with intent

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NewActivityClassName.class);
myIntent.putExtra("name","test");
myIntent.putExtra("videourl","www.deom.mp3");
startActivity(myIntent);

// getIntent() is a method from the started activity

Intent myIntent = getIntent(); // get date from previous intent
String name= myIntent.getStringExtra("name"); // will return "name"
String videourl= myIntent.getStringExtra("videourl");
```

Comment: Ok thanks, so should i look more into intent?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating new activity or layout for each button click if you want to play the video and show some text there?

You can create single activity with one layout containing videoview and textarea. On click of each button create a new intent and pass the url and text.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("textData","Your Text");
intent.putExtra("videoUrl","Your Url");
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the oncreate() method of the activity get the values from intent.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me. :)

Comment: Well i want each button to go to a different video, not all the same, will this work?